# React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency - I'm using a fn from a context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my component, I have the following (for brevity I've only included relevant code snippets):

```
const authContext = useAuthContext();
const projectContext = useProjectContext();


useEffect(() => {
  const loadProject = async (userId: string) => {
    await projectContext.loadProjectsForUser(userId);
  }
  
  if (authContext.user) {
    loadProject(authContext.user.id).catch().finally();
  }
}, [authContext.user]);
```

However, eslint tells me:

`React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'projectContext'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

Can I ignore this or do I need to add `projectContext` to the dependency list? It has a bunch of other values, so wouldn't this get called each time one of those updates? What's the best way to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Move  function const loadProject = async (userId: string) => {
    await projectContext.loadProjectsForUser(userId);
  }
  out of useeffect

Comment: @Oleg - you'll still have to add the new `loadProject` to dependencies, but now it'll fire on every render... to make that work you'd need `useCallback()` but then you have the same problem, you've just shifted it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to add `projectContext` to the dependencies, and to make sure it doesn't trigger a project reload on every change inside `projectContext` you can update your `if` statement to something like:

```
if (authContext.user && projectNotLoaded) { // ... }
```

Shifting the function out of useEffect won't help in this instance.. you'll just have to add the new function to dependencies and it'll fire on every render.

To stop that you'd have to put the new function into a `useCallback()` which will require the `projectContext` as a dependency anyway, so you've just shifted the problem.

As to why you'll want to include `projectContext` with your dependencies there's a great explanation here:

https://betterprogramming.pub/stop-lying-to-react-about-missing-dependencies-10612e9aeeda

Answer (score 0):

1,just add `projectContext` to effect dep array, **this will trigger effect when `projectContext` changes**, if `projectContext` never change this way is fine

2, as @Oleg pointed, Move function `const loadProject = async (userId: string) => { await projectContext.loadProjectsForUser(userId); }` out of useeffect, **then `projectContext` wont update when it is updated**, because it will use the value in first render (effect function is not updated when prop/context change), if `projectContext` never change this way is fine

3, use ref to store `projectContext` when it's updated, then you do not add dep array, just a ref and another effect

```js
const authContext = useAuthContext();
const projectContext = useProjectContext();

let ref = createRef(projectContext.loadProjectsForUser)

useEffect(() => {
  const loadProject = async (userId: string) => {
    await ref.current(userId);
  }
  
  if (authContext.user) {
    loadProject(authContext.user.id).catch().finally();
  }
}, [authContext.user]);

useEffect(()=>{
  ref.current = projectContext.loadProjectsForUser
},[projectContext.loadProjectsForUser])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure authContext and projectContext to get only the value you  needed in component. Then you can mention only those values which is used in useEffect in dependency array.

```
const {user} = useAuthContext();
const {loadProjectsForUser} = useProjectContext();

const {id:userId} = user;

useEffect(() => {
  // Some code here
 }, [userId, loadProjectsForUser])
```